# Reference External Directory in Symfony

Tags: git, symfony, phpstorm, directory-structure, symfony-2.3

**Situation**

I have a *Base* Symfony app which can be compared to an abstract class.
I have multiple *Customer* Symfony apps, all based from the *Base* app.
*Customer* apps are simple websites, each with different (read-only) data, themes, etc.

*Base* app - does **NOT** function as stand-alone

- .htaccess files, AppKernel, config.yml, etc.
- multiple vendor bundles
- *Base* bundle with some base views
- lacks Controller
- lacks routing
- lacks customer-specific resources

*Customer* - contains elements missing from *Base* app

- "injected" into *Base* app
- Controller(s)
- routing
- customer-specific resources (views, css, js, data, etc.)

Using git, and would prefer to create a git repo out of the *Base* code, with each *Customer* repo referencing *Base* repo as submodule.
This keeps *Base* code in one repository and maintains a clean separation between *Customer* repos.

```
root\ - (Customer repo)
    Customer\ - (Customer-specific files)
    Symfony\ - (Base app submodule repo)
       app\
       src\
          MyCompany\
             BaseBundle\
       vendor\
       web\
```

**Sticking Point**

Unable to get Symfony to recognize the `Customer\` folder, nor any of its contents.

**Specs**

- Symfony 2.3
- Git
- Apache 2.4.4
- PhpStorm
- Windows 7 x64

**Failed Attempts**

- adding *Customer* bundle to *AppKernel.php* `registerBundles`
- registering the `Customer\` folder in *autoload.php*

Answer (score 0):

Create a Junction symbolic link using the external `Customer\` directory as the source and the destination inside `MyCompany\` directory.

In Symfony (submodule) repo's *.gitignore*, add `customer/` to ignore the junction symlink.

```
root\ - (Customer repo)
    Customer\ - (symlink source)
    Symfony\  - (git submodule)
       app\
       src\
          MyCompany\
             BaseBundle\
             Customer\ - (Junction symlink)
       vendor\
       web\
```

[Complete Guide to Symbolic Links (symlinks) on Windows or Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)